# Best practices to add a dynamic number of buttons/links making a POST call in spring MVC

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc, post, hyperlink

I'm working on a project which needs a display of details of all the students in an organization and a link to Edit or Delete the details of the corresponding student. It looks like this, where Edit and Delete are two hyperlinks calling two different controllers.

[image]

Since the hyperlink takes the value("student id" to be edited/deleted) as url parameter is there any better way to pass the value to the controller using POST call? Is it advisable to create dynamic number of FORM elements for each button/link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a hidden input for your student id and use a javascript function to set the value on every button click.

```
<input name="id" type="hidden" id="student_id">


<input type="button" onclick="edit(id)">Edit</input>
<input type="button" onclick="delete(id)">Delete</input>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function edit(id){
     $("#stutent_id").val(id);
     $("form").submit();
    }

    function delete(id){
     $("#stutent_id").val(id);
     $("form").submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the "$ ("form").submit ();" this isn't working.

Comment: try to use form id :  $("#form_id").submit() and make sure you import jquery.js